# Python import all * from dynamically created module

Tags: python, python-importlib

I have found many variations for importing dynamically created/named modules by reference to their names as text, but all import the module as a whole and do not seem to facilitate importing all * ....

In my case, the objects within the file are dynamically created and named, so their identities cannot be discovered beforehand.

This works, but is there a better way perhaps using importlib ?

```
PREFIX = "my_super_new"

active_data_module = "{0}_data_module".format(PREFIX)

exec("from {0} import *".format(active_data_module))
```

Comment: It's one thing to use `from foo import *` when you know what `foo` is. How will you even know what was imported if you don't know the value of `active_data_module`?

Comment: @chepner the active data module is generated at runtime from configurations that are user defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `vars` with the module. This would return a dictionary of all attributes on the module (I think). Then you can assign the dictionary to the `globals` dictionary to make it accessible in the current module:

```
import importlib

PREFIX = "my_super_new"
active_data_module = "{0}_data_module".format(PREFIX)

module = importlib.import_module(active_data_module)

globals().update(vars(module))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Peter Wood's answer, I created a small utility function:

```
import importlib

def import_everything_from_module_by_name(module_name):
    globals().update(vars(importlib.import_module(module_name)))

modules_for_import = [
    module_a,
    module_b,
    module_c
    ]

for module_name in modules_for_import:
    import_everything_from_module_by_name(module_name)
```

Comment: Just to note, this will only update `globals` for that particular module. It might not behave the way you think if you call the function from a different module.